# Compile C++ code for Mac (Boost Minkowski Methods)

Tags: c#, c++, macos

I would like to ask how to compile C++ code to .dll for **Mac**.

Currently I have windows application that is written in .NET C# language and it calls C++ .dll through PInvoke.

I am compiling several Boost library functions according to this 
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q1Clz.png) using macros:

```
cl /Ox -I "B:\Libs\Boost\boost_1_68_0" /LD minkowski.cc
```

Now the software I have is perfectly working on Windows, but users ask me if I can make it work on mac. I can run C# application using .NET framework on Mac computers, but C++ .dll simply cannot not be loaded. Therefore I would like to ask if anyone has experience how to compile that minkowski.cc to .dll for mac users? I do not have mac computer and never used it and my C++ knowledge is somehow not big. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Anyone could help?